# Unit test class runs old version in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, junit, junit4, maven-surefire-plugin

I have a JUnit test class in my project which is updated incrementally - I add tests every few weeks and sometimes modify the tests' code.

Surprisingly, when I run the test class using eclipse JUnit Runner 4, it runs my old code (before the update) and not the new one. I can change the code, add or remove tests but it still runs the old code.

I tried to isolate the problem and run a single test that I've just written and got the infamous "Unrooted tests" error without any stack trace to give me a clue what the problem is.

[image: JUnit runner response. test7() is indeed within the compiled test class]

I did some research and according to a few other threads here, many people encountered this problem with regards to JUnit 3 \ JUnit 4 compatibility, but this is not the case here - I annotate all my tests with `@Test` and I do NOT extends the `TestCase` class.

Cleaning / Building all eclipse projects doesn't help.
However, this problem does work itself around when I mvn clean install my project, but this takes too much time.
Also, renaming the class (Alt+Shift+R in eclipse) gets the new code to run immediately, but renaming it back to its original (and valid) name, gets the old code to run again (WTF?)

Help would be appreciated,
10x

Comment: If it runs old code it **has** old code, either in source or compiled. Do you have old code somewhere, maybe even in a .jar that happens to be in the class path?

Comment: I guess I do somewhere, but assuming eclipse has compiled it (which it did), isn't the eclipse runner supposed to run the code it was instructed to run?

Comment: Is it possible you've got Eclipse configured in such a way that the test runner is using compiled classes under `target` but the Eclipse compiler is outputting to a different folder (it's `bin` by default)?  That might explain why a Maven build resolves the issue.

Comment: @KidCrippler which Eclipse version are you using? That's an important information to provide

Comment: @A.DiMatteo Sure, my eclipse version is Luna Service Release 1a (4.4.1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem on my own (inspired by a comment contributed by Harlard).
After examining the target directory of my project, I noticed that the test-classes dir inside it doesn't include the binaries of my test.
I then noticed that I misplaced the classes within src/test/java and put them in a package structure that doesn't conform to the package structure of my project, they were direct sub-directories of src/test/java.
Therefore, eclipse didn't put them in the correct place and the only way to generate binaries for them was by executing a maven build.
After refactoring all my test classes to the correct package structure, everything worked perfectly.

Comment: Thank you.  I had to specify the `output` directory explicitly in my `.classpath` file to get it to work: `<classpathentry kind="src" path="src/test/java" output="target/test-classes"/>`.  Prior to this I didn't have the `output` part so there were compiled versions under the `target` directory but not in the correct place for Junit execution from within Eclipse.

Comment: This is it. Eclipse is compiling your test cases, but may be putting them somewhere else. Go to your filesystem. Look closely at your target/test-classes and also look at any typos in project build path where you might be specifying a slightly different path. Try to find out where Eclipse is storing the class files.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. It was due to a defective .classpath. Removing this .classpath and re-importing the project, generates a correct .classpath and  fixed the environment.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be manually deleting the "target" folder of the project and rebuilding it. This should solve all problems of this kind.